# Возможно ли вообще отправлять данные на сервер, которые хранятся в экземпляре vue

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js, post

ситуация такова, есть экземпляр vue , который способен создавать таблицы в SPA приложении , в эти таблицы можно вписывать имена и фамилии людей. То есть у экземпляра есть свойство(в data{})в виде массива, который хранит эти таблицы и есть переменная, которая  хранит еще один массив, в котором данные на пользователя
(извиняюсь за кривое объяснение) https://github.com/AmanKKK/ListEditor.git (тут весь код)
[image: структура таблицы]

Comment: уточню, есть в data переменная cards[] в ней есть переменная tarefas[], в которой информация, которая выводится на экран

Comment: Возможно. Можно отправлять вообще всё, что угодно. В том числе и данные, которые хранятся в экземпляре vue

Comment: можно будет узнать, каким образом отправить свойства экземпляра на сервер,
я искал и наткнулся на AJAX , AXIOS, даже fetch ,но там только получение, как отправить такие данные, я пытался , пока что не получается

Answer (score 1):

вот маленький пример работы с Axios. Это супер библиотека, сейчас пользуюсь только ей для общения с сервером. https://github.com/axios/axios

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input v-model="search"><button v-if="search" type="button" @click="sendSearch">Send</button>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendSearch() {
      axios.post("/search/", {
        search: this.search,
        lastName: "Flintstone",
      }).then(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
        }
      );
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо за данный ответ, только не я не уверен,что правильно понял строчку с кодом  axios.post("/search/", это же путь к файлу на сервере,который хранит данные,и по которому вы проводите поиск? Я смотрел как делать запрос через axios , и если не ошибаюсь на месте "/search/" указывают url сервера

Comment: "/search/" это API. Если ты используешь PHP, то это может быть путь к скрипту php.

Comment: @AmanShygaibaev это и есть url. url не обязательно начинать `http://server.com...`. Тогда получается относительный url. серверную часть угадывает и подставляет сам браузер. Учите матчасть.